# How to group a dictionary by the first character of their key-values and sort them in ascending order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to group the dictionary by the first character of their key-value, find the minimum and maximum value and sort them in ascending order of the maximum value found.

```
dict = {'1,1': [1.0, 2.0], '3,1': [5.0, 8.0], '2,2': [3.0, 9.0], '2,1': [3.0, 11.0]}
```

The dictionary after grouping, finding the max and min value, and sort in ascending order of their maximum values should be:

```
dict = {'1': [1.0, 2.0], '3': [5.0, 8.0], '2': [3.0, 11.0]}
```

Comment: what if min and max are the same? Or if a list is a singleton? Are the values always lists of length 2?

Comment: @enke min and max will not be the same and the values will always be a list of length 2

Comment: @j1-lee yes it's the minimum of the value of dict['2']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can keep concatenating the lists grouped by `k[0]`, and then take minimum and maximum of the lists:

```py
dct = {'1,1': [1.0, 2.0], '3,1': [5.0, 8.0], '2,2': [3.0, 9.0], '2,1': [3.0, 11.0]}

output = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    output[k[0]] = output.get(k[0], []) + v

output = {k: [min(v), max(v)] for k, v in output.items()}
print(output) # {'1': [1.0, 2.0], '3': [5.0, 8.0], '2': [3.0, 11.0]}
```

Alternatively, if you are willing to use `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict # this at the beginning of the script

output = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in dct.items():
    output[k[0]] += v

output = {k: [min(v), max(v)] for k, v in output.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

this works but maybe someone has a more elegant answer:

```
dictionnary = {'1,1': [1.0, 2.0], '3,1': [5.0, 8.0], '2,2': [3.0, 9.0], '2,1': [3.0, 11.0]}
a = [i[0] for i in dictionnary.keys()]
b = dict.fromkeys(a)

for i in b:
    b[i] = []
    for j in dictionnary:
        if j[0] == i:
            if b[i]:
                if dictionnary[j][0]<b[i][0]:
                    b[i][0] = dictionnary[j][0]
                if dictionnary[j][1]>b[i][1]:
                    b[i][1] = dictionnary[j][1]
            else:
                b[i] = dictionnary[j]
b
```

Output:

```
{'1': [1.0, 2.0], '3': [5.0, 8.0], '2': [3.0, 11.0]}
```

Also, you shouldn't overwrite the builtin python `dict`